# upload file to sql table using a path

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to upload a file to a MySQL table using a path (the file will be save on the server `asd` in the table a link for him).  Here is what I've done:

My view is:

```
<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'doc_ordered_recieved'); ?>
<?php echo $form->fileField($model,'doc_ordered_recieved'); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'doc_ordered_recieved'); ?>
</div>
```

My model is:

```
array('doc_ordered_recieved','file','types'=>'pdf', 'allowEmpty'=>true, 'on'=>'insert,update'),
```

and my controller is:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
$model=new Orders;


if(isset($_POST['Orders']))
{

    $model->attributes=$_POST['Orders'];
    $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'doc_ordered_recieved');
    if($model->save())
    {
        if(!empty($uploadedFile))  // check if uploaded file is set or not
        {

            if($model->doc_ordered_recieved== null || empty($model->doc_ordered_recieved)){
                $rnd = rand(0,9999);// generate random number between 0-9999
                $fileName = "{$rnd}-{$uploadedFile}";
                $model->doc_ordered_recieved= $fileName;
            }
            $uploadedFile->saveAs(dirname(__FILE__)..'/files/'. $model->doc_ordered_recieved);
            // redirect to success page
        }
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->oid));
    }
}
    $this->render('create',array('model'=>$model,
));
}
```

The table is defined as `varchar` is that ok????

The file should be saved in `d:\xampp\htdocs\filse`

Please help me it always says: `doc_ordered_recieved can't be blank`

Comment: what line the error happens?

Comment: when i press the add butten its said that its like i didn add the file but ofcours i add it